# Error when using the NodeJs and sed to create the new Kubernetes config file

Tags: node.js, sed, kubernetes, shelljs

I am using the Shelljs and sed command to generate the new K8S config file

```
shell.exec(`sed -e s%${server}%${endpoint}%g -e s%${certificate}%${cert}%g config-temp`)
shell.exec("cat config-temp | tee config")
```

Then I am checking if the K8S cluster is working by running

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

The error message looks like

```
error: Error loading config file "~/.kube/config": yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

However, if I copy all the content from the `config-temp`, then paste it into the `config`,  `kubectl cluster-info` works.

I haven't found same error messages above online. I am just wondering if anyone come across the similar issue. Any helpers

Comment: @EdMorton . Thanks for your input. the sed part has no problem, I guess I haven't phased my problem clear enough. The problem is when I replace the certificate with cert, the text in the cert variable has some special characters, which cannot be recognized by K8S.

Answer (score 1):

try `sed -Ei` instead of `sed -e`, really edit the `config-temp`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you guys input. the sed part has no problem, I guess I haven't phased my problem clear enough. The problem is when I replace the certificate with cert, the text in the cert variable has some special characters , which cannot be recognized by K8S.